# The value interpretation of eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

My question is may be strange but I wanna lie it any way.
The direction of an eigenvector is the most important as we normalize it. This view is right but what about the value of this eigenvector in the high dimensional. May be the idea I want to clear is still not so clear. Suppose I have some face images and I follow the Principal Component Analysis steps to compute the eigenvectors on covariance matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface
http://www.cse.unr.edu/~zehang/research/gender/methodology.html

The first eigenvector(eigenface you can see it in the figures shown in the above two links) has a pattern which is very close to the face image. In his case, the values of the first eigenvector have some meaning, is it right? and what these values represent?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean. If we assume that facial features are some finite dimensional vector space, then we're interpreting that data along some eigenbasis which makes sense to our eyes.  I don't think there's any inherent ordering in the eigenvectors, unless for some reason the facial lighting eigenvectors have particularly large eigenvalues?

Comment: @Frank McGovern I think there is a hidden meaning about the values of the eigenvectors itself because if you apply the same process (PCA) on another dataset, you will end up  with the same result. The first eigenvector which has the largest eigenvalue has a very close pattern to the studied object. It is not related to the lighting conditions. Of course not only the first eigenvector but the second, third...etc will have the same pattern somehow. This point which I am trying to interpret. Why??